# Android ImageView radial gradient similar to a spotlight?

Tags: android, imageview

I'm trying to make my imageview have a radial gradient background that goes from solid white to a transparent white on the outside.  Here's my SHAPE definition that I use as the ImageView background.  The problem is that I end up with a solid white circle for my background, not the semi transparent edges like I want:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle"> 
    <gradient 
        android:startColor="#ffffff00"
        android:endColor="#ffffffff"
        android:centerX="50%"
        android:centerY="50%"
        android:gradientRadius="50%"
        android:type="radial"/>
    <corners 
        android:bottomRightRadius="20dp" 
        android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp" 
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp" 
        android:topRightRadius="20dp"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.  I had two errors:  the first being that percentages are not supported in gradientRadius and the second being that the first two places in startColor and endColor are the transparency values.  It's AARRGGBB not RRGGBBAA.  Here is the fixed Shape definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle"> 
    <gradient 
        android:startColor="#ffffffff"
        android:endColor="#00ffffff"
        android:gradientRadius="36"
        android:type="radial"/>
    <corners 
        android:bottomRightRadius="20dp" 
        android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp" 
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp" 
        android:topRightRadius="20dp"/> 
</shape>
```